# How do I access the JSON response with jQuery.Ajax for a 400 error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery, I'm submitting forms to the server. When there is a validation error, I receive a 400 error from the server, and the body of the document is valid JSON. I would like to know how to access the data returned from the server.

My .error callback function on the jQuery.Ajax object is never called, so I'm using .statusCode{400} function. This runs just fine, however none of the arguments contain the response body.

Comment: if the request was bad, you shouldn't need to send more body content. Yes, i understand it can be desirable to tell *why* it was bad, or some other nice data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some browsers' XHR implementations refuse to provide the response body if the HTTP status is not 2xx. What I've had to resort to in API design where I couldn't control my clients was to do something like always return 200 and indicate success/failure/status in some other way (e.g., as a top-level attribute in the JSON response).

Comment: What browsers are you talking about here?

Comment: Can't comment on browser support, but typically you can access JSON data in the response with jqXHR.responseJSON, and jqXHR is the first argument passed to callback functions.

Answer (score 8):

I try to get json response with a status 400, and it works on IE7,8 and 9, Firefox and Chrome (Safari not tested).

```
...
error: function(xhr) {
   error(xhr.responseText);
}
...
```

Comment: This is the best answer i've found, and can easily be extended to parse the JSON response and use properties of it:                 

              ```error: function(xhr) {
                    toastr.info(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).error);
                }```

Comment: xhr.responseJSON is also available.

Answer (score 1):

I have had no trouble using statusCode in the callback, However, statusCode as a callback function **Does NOT** return any data.

[jQuery.Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

I think you should try a different approach on how to handle validation errors in the server side, to return status code 200, but with a parameter like "error_count" and go from there.

can you post some of the code you are using (just $.ajax you are using...) ?

Comment: Not true. (Or no longer true?) status code callback receives jqXHR as the first argument, which has json in responseJSON property.

Answer (score 0):

For me (Chrome), responseText property of the xhr response contains only "BAD REQUEST" when statusCode is 400.  Thanks Steven for your response; I was struggling with this since in Postman I could get the json data I was returning from my REST controller, but couldn't find it on the jQuery Ajax response.

Comment: is this meant to be an answer? the second half of your answer should probably have been a comment.

Comment: It sounds like the response body of that particular response was bad request. This does not apply to all responses from all endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

"If json is specified, the response is parsed using jQuery.parseJSON before being passed, as an object, to the success handler. The parsed JSON object is made available through the **responseJSON property of the jqXHR object.**"

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

If you're specifying your callback with `statusCode` as mentioned in the question:

"If the request is successful, the status code functions take the same parameters as the success callback; **if it results in an error** (including 3xx redirect), **they take the same parameters as the error callback.**" (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)